# Heroku - Connetar com mongoDB addon mLab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, heroku

Preciso me conetar com a base de dados Mongo usando o addOn mLab.
Mas não estou a conseguir inserir nem listar, quando executo em modo local está a funcionar.
Tenho a variável configurada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma ideia do que pode ser?

O meu app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var app = express();


    // Here we find an appropriate database to connect to, defaulting to
    // localhost if we don't find one.
    //'mongodb://heroku_28mj3757:mo88w5coethti7a0kd3puctgsf@ds031597.mlab.com:31597/heroku_28mj3757';
    //MONGODB_URI
    var uristring =
    process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
    process.env.MONGOHQ_URL||
    'mongodb://localhost/HelloMongoose';

    //


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

    // The http server will listen to an appropriate port, or default to
    // port 5000.

    console.log("O valor da porta é:  " +process.env.PORT);
    console.log("O valor da porta é:  " +uristring);
    var theport = process.env.PORT || 5000;


        // Makes connection asynchronously.  Mongoose will queue up database
    // operations and release them when the connection is complete.
    mongoose.connect(uristring, function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
      console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
      } else {
      console.log ('Succeeded connected to: ' + uristring);
      }
    });

module.exports = app;
```

Rotas onde faço  inserção/listar;

```
   var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: String,
      age:  Number
    });


var PUser = mongoose.model('PowerUsers', userSchema);



router.post('/insert', function(req, res, next) {
  //res.send({nome:"nome"}); 
  //console.("Ola mundo");
  //var Inscricaoo = mongoose.model('pessoas', inscricao);

  console.log("Route -  passou aqui ");

    // Creating one user.
    var johndoe = new PUser ({
      "name":"sara",
      "age": 25
    });



    // Saving it to the database.
    johndoe.save(function (err, result) {
        console.log("Errroooooo" + err);
    });

    res.send(johndoe);

});


router.get('/userlist', function(req, res, next) {
  //res.send({nome:"nome"}); 
  //console.("Ola mundo");
  //var Inscricaoo = mongoose.model('pessoas', inscricao);

  console.log("Route user list-  passou aqui ");
       // list all .
  PUser.find({}, function(err, users) {
    var userMap = {};

    users.forEach(function(user) {
      userMap[user._id] = user;
    });

    res.send(userMap);  
  });

});
```

Logs do heroku:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo, ao fazer o deploy no heroku, chega a aparecer alguma mensagem no log? Se não me engano, para ver o log, apos você dar deploy, use o comando "heroku --logs ", ou então no próprio navegador em sua conta do heroku tem uma área que você consegue monitorar estes logs também.

Comment: Olá, aparece o erro de conecção a BD, (não tenho acesso ao erro agora) mas era qualquer coisa como, mongo error -  first conection faill... Logo adiciono o erro a pergunta...

Comment: Confirme assim que possível a mensagem de erro que lhe aparece. Tente confirmar se esta URL de conexão realmente está correta, tentando se conectar fora do heroku, via linha de comando. Caso consiga, talvez pode ser erro de timeout da conexão com o mongodb.

Comment: O erro está se derivando porque está sendo passado **undefined** na String de conexão do mongoose.
Você já tentou conectar com a String de conexão "chumbada" em texto mesmo, sem utilizar pelas variáveis de ambiente do Heroku?

Pegue a uri de conexão assim:
`heroku config | grep MONGODB_URI`

E tente alterar:
`var uristring =
    process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
    process.env.MONGOHQ_URL||
    'mongodb://localhost/HelloMongoose';`

Para: 
`var uristring = "mongodb://usuariododb:senhadodb@host:porta/nomedodb" `

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o erro está sendo derivado porque está sendo passado **undefined** para a String de conexão. Pela foto que você mandou, a variável de ambiente para a conexão está sendo passada na variável: MONGODB_URI, mas em seu código, ela não está sendo chamada. Tente alterar

```
var uristring =
process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
process.env.MONGOHQ_URL||
'mongodb://localhost/HelloMongoose';
```

Por:

```
var uristring = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
```